# Ruby on rails_format form fields with bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I want to format form fields with Boostrap CSS.

I have following code in form view file:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :country %>
  <%= f.select :country, ["India","USA","Australia"] %>
</p>
```

I want it to format as:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>India</option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>Australia</option>
</select>
```

I have tried few different ways that I thought would work, but no success.

Comment: `<%= f.select :country, ["India","USA","Australia"], {}, { :class => 'form-control' } %>`

try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :country, options_for_select(["India", "USA", "Australia"]), class: "form-control" %>
```

It will generate the desired output.